# MVC 5 EF Soft Delete

Tags: entity-framework

I based on the below link to implement logical delet.https://github.com/rowanmiller/Demo-TechEd2014
The problem is that this solution removes all records that contain a field removed

```
[SoftDelete("IsDelete")]
public class Pusher
{
    [Key]
    public int IdPusher { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

   public bool IsDelete { get; set; }

}

[SoftDelete("IsDelete")]
public class Task
{
    [Key]
    public int IdTask { get; set; }     

    public int IdPusher { get; set; }
    public virtual Pusher Pusher { get; set; }  

    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }        

}
```

If I delete a pusher, all task containing it are no longer seen by the method GetAll

Comment: You may try with making IdPusher nullable `public int? IdPusher { get; set; }`, and see if it makes a difference